# Java: Storing newInstance in a variable

Tags: java, class, reflection, nullpointerexception

I have been trying to store one of my classes(loaded using reflection) in an object using java.lang's newInstace() method. It seems to work within the method I create the newInstace() in, however outside it, the var throws a null pointer exception... Really makes no sense to me, does anyone know how to fix this?

Class:

```
public class ScriptManager {

public static Class currentScript;
public static Object ScriptInstance;
public static int State;
// 0 = Not Running
// 1 = Running
// 2 = Paused

public static void runScript() {
    try {
        ScriptInstance = currentScript.newInstance();
        currentScript.getMethod("run").invoke(ScriptInstance);
        State = 1;
        MainFrame.onPause();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static void pauseScript() {
    try {
        currentScript.getMethod("pause").invoke(ScriptInstance);
        State = 2;
        MainFrame.onPause();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static void stopScript() {
    try {
        currentScript.getMethod("stop").invoke(ScriptInstance);
        State = 0;
        MainFrame.onStop();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

Error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at Bot.ScriptManager.pauseScript(ScriptManager.java:29)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your use of `static` is messing you up. Try something like this:

```
   public class ScriptManager {

      private Class currentScript;
      private Object scriptInstance;
      private int state;

      public ScriptManager() {
        try {
            scriptInstance = currentScript.newInstance();
            currentScript.getMethod("run").invoke(scriptInstance);
            //the rest
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
      }

      public void pauseScript() {
        try {
            currentScript.getMethod("pause").invoke(scriptInstance);
            //the rest
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
      }
//the rest
}
```

On a side note, use lower CamelCase for your variable names.

And keep your member variables `private` in this scenario.

Comment: I removed static, It still doesnt work :(, and what is CamelCase?

Comment: Well, as my sample shows, it isn't enough to just remove `static`. You need to create a constructor and so on. Look more carefully at the sample.

Comment: Here is information about CamelCase: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CamelCase#Programming_and_coding. The bottom line is just rename your variables to start with a lowercase character. Not required but just convention.

Comment: Glad to help. Good luck with your project and your studies of Java!